# Mac Pro, Boot into OSX without EFI after Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, efi

I have a Mac Pro, early 2008. I installed Windows 10 using bootcamp.

The mac came with an 8800gt, but I had a GTX680 from my other PC which I put in the mac, it is not the mac version so I don't get the EFI menu. 
The mac boots up into windows, if I hold option I obviously don't get the menu, but is there any way I can boot into OSX without switching out the graphics card every time?
Or do I have to get the mac edition of the card?

Comment: If you boot into mac Bios (open firmware) with Cmd + Opt + O + F, wait for it to load and type `mac-boot`, does it boot into mac? If it does, do you get the standard option menu next boot?

Comment: I tried holding them down and it just boots to windows without any prompt?

Comment: my mistake. That applied to older macs. Does Command+S boot into single-user mode?

Comment: And will resetting PRAM/NVRAM work? (Comman-Option-P-R on boot. Hold until you hear the chime play 2 times).

Comment: I managed to get around the problem by putting the old card back in, removing Windows 10 and installing Windows 7, which support the Boot camp support software, now I can click the icon and click 'Restart into OSX' and from OSC I can choose my startup disk to switch back to Windows